# Landscape, A3/A4 paper with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, header-footer, margins, paper-size, landscape

With `pdflatex`, it seems easy to get a landscape document, on A3 paper. One only needs to add `[landscape,a3paper]` or `[landscape,a4paper]` to the document class options. With `xelatex`, however, these options do not seem to work.

How can I get a landscape mode document, on A3 or A4 paper, with 2 cm margins and no page numbers, headers, or footers in XeTeX for all of the pages of a document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for document layout and setting the page style (including `plain`) to `empty`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape,a3paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\pagestyle{empty}% Set page style to empty
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty% Make plain page style equivalent to empty page style
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\chapter{First and only chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

The above MWE sets the document page style to `empty`, which has no header/footer nor header/footer rule. It then also sets the `plain` page style `(\ps@plain`) to be exactly the same as that of `empty` (`\ps@empty`), since these styles are used as the first pages for chapters within the `book` and `report` document classes (including [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)).

You could also have obtained a similar style (if small modifications are required at a later stage) by using the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). For that, the following preamble modifications would result in the same output:

```
%...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Default is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Default is 0.4pt
\fancyhead{}% Clear fancy page style header
\fancyfoot{}% Clear fancy page style footer
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set page style to fancy
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% Make plain page style equivalent to fancy page style
\makeatletter
%...
```

Comment: Heh, good luck staying on the right line when reading that `;-)`